# Eclipse "run as" missing groovy script

Tags: eclipse, groovy

When I use eclipse to run a groovy file, the "run as" only shows two choices which are "Groovy Console" and "Java Application". It should has a "Groovy Script" as default but currently it does not.

To run the file, I have to use "run configurations" to choose the "Groovy Script". Are there any way that I could add "Groovy Script" back to the "run as" list?

Comment: What does the content of your source file look like?  If you have a class with a static main method, then Java Application is the right choice.  Groovy Script only shows up if you have statements at the top level.

Comment: is your file extension `.groovy` ?

Comment: Yes, all the files are groovy files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your file in Eclipse using the "New" -> "Others" -> "Groovy Type" eclipse generated a class file. The class files cannot be executed as scripts even if they have the .groovy extension.

Try to create a completely new file with .groovy extension with the following content, as example:

```
println GroovySystem.version
```

Now the menu "Run as..." -> "Groovy script" is active. The content of your file must be script specific statements in order to get the "Groovy script" menu active.